# Kotlin Coroutines - unlimited stream to fan out batches

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm looking to implement a pipeline for processing an infinite stream of messages. I'm new to coroutines and trying to follow along with the docs but I'm not confident I'm doing the right thing.

My infinite stream is of batches of records and I'd like to fan out the processing of each record to a coroutine, wait for a batch to finish (to log stats and stuff) before continuing to the next batch.

```
                    -> process [record] \   
source -> [records] -> process [record]  -> [log batch stats]
                    -> process [record] /   

         |------------------- while(true) -------------------|
```

What I had planned is to have 2 `Channel`s, one for the infinite stream, and one for the intermediate records that will fill up and empty on each batch.

```
runBlocking {
  val infinite: Channel<List<Record>> = produce { send(source.getBatch()) }
  val records = Channel<Record>(Channel.Factory.UNLIMITED)

  while(true) {
    infinite.receive().forEach { records.send(it) }
    while(!records.isEmpty()) {
      launch { process(records.receive()) }
    }

    // ??? Wait for jobs?

    logBatchStats()
  }

}
```

From googling, it seems that waiting for jobs is discouraged, plus I wasn't sure if calling `.map` on a channel will actually receive messages to convert them to jobs:

```
records.map { record -> launch { process(record) } }
```

yields a `Channel<Job>`. It seems I can call `.toList()` on it to collapse it, but then I need to join the jobs? Again, google suggested to do that by having a parent job, but I'm not really sure how to do that with `launch`.

Anyway, very much a n00b to this.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a reason to have two channels. You could directly iterate over the list of records. And you should use `async` instead of `launch`. Then you can use `await` or even better `awaitAll` for the list of results.

```
val infinite: ReceiveChannel<List<Record>> = produce { ... }

while(true) {
    val resultsDeferred = infinite.receive().map {
        async {
            process(it)
        }
    }

    val results = resultsDeferred.awaitAll()

    logBatchStats()
}
```